# Trouble opening Excel document via python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm not a very advanced python user and am having trouble with a program I'm working on. I was able to get it to work without problems on one computer but now when I try to run in on a different computer it is not working.

Basically I'm trying to open a excel file and write stuff into it and then save as.

Here is the error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aainstall\Desktop\Python\DD\DDcreatemacrosheets10_27_14.py", line 70, in <module>
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Allmacro.xlsx")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\Workbooks.py", line 78, in Open
    , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "'Allmacro.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.\n\nIf you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Here is the relevant code.

```
import xlrd
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')


for i in ListofDDlists:
    cellnumber = 0

    if i == AllCD:
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Allmacro.xlsx")
        print (wb)
        excel.Visible = True
        ws = wb.Worksheets("MyData")
```

I'm pretty puzzled about what the problem might be and about to to fix it. The file it is looking for is there and is in the right spot. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Both computers I am trying to run this on are using Windows 7. The computer this works on is using Python 3.3 while the computer it does not work on is using Python 3.4. Both computers have Excel 2010 installed.

Comment: Why do you import ```xlrd```?

Comment: Sorry probably shouldn't have included that as relevant code. It is used for an earlier part of the program to read in some data from another file.

Comment: Are you sure that your file ```Allmacro``` is actually a ```.xlsx``` file?  Excel files with macros can be ```.xlsm``` as well

Comment: Yep. I'm certain. And this same code works without a problem on my other computer.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all the relevant differences between the two computers? (i.e. OS, python version, module version, etc)

Comment: Try typing the full path to the file when you `Open` it

Comment: In filename, you should mention the full path . I also got same problem, Also be sure with file name and extension.

Comment: Adding the full file path fixed it! Thank you!